# In Java dynamically add string with properties file message?

Tags: java

I am able to read the message from properties file where i added all messages with `key/value` pair

```
message.template.success.equipment.create = Equipment template created successfully
message.template.success.equipment.create.termination = Termination template created successfully
message.template.success.equipment.update = Equipment template updated successfully
message.template.success.termination.update = Termination template updated successfully
```

for reading message from the properties file i have create a class with following code

```
public class PropertyReader {

    private static PropertyReader instance = null;
    private ResourceBundle bundleResource;
    private ResourceBundle bundleResourceMenu;
    private ResourceBundle bundleResourceMessage;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PropertyReader.class);

    private PropertyReader() {}

    private PropertyReader(Locale locale) {
        log.info("Property Reader loading files with locale : "+locale.getLanguage());
        bundleResourceMenu = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bsm-portal-menu",locale);
        bundleResource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bsmResource",locale);
        bundleResourceMessage = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bsm-portal-message",locale);
        log.info("**** BundleResourceMessage *****");
     
    }

    public static synchronized PropertyReader getInstance(Locale locale) {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new PropertyReader(locale);
        return instance;
    }


    public String getBundleResource(String propKey) {
        return this.bundleResource.getString(propKey);
    }

    public String getBundleResourceMenu(String propKey) {
        return this.bundleResourceMenu.getString(propKey);
    }

    public String getBundleResourceMessage(String propKey) {
        return this.bundleResourceMessage.getString(propKey);
    }


}
```

Upto this everything fine.

Now I want to make this type of message dynamic

```
 message = "Entities " + appenMessage.toString() + " are already added in another association";
```

here `appenMessage` variable have a dynamically generated String value which I have to append with message. Is it possible to incorporate such kind with properties file ?

Comment: Use MessageFormat or String.format(). Just store the pattern in the properties file. Note that your getInstance() method above doesn't make much sense: if I ask a PropertyReader for French, then all the PropertyReaders I'll get later, for English, Chinese and Spanish, will all be for French.

Comment: @JBNizet Look more sense to me with your comment so can you please provide any example to make appropriate .

Comment: Read the javadoc. It has examples.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this tutorial about [Compound Messages:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/messageFormat.html)

Personally, I tend to do it with simple

```
 bundle.getString("key").replace("{0}", firstParam);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`java.text.MessageFormat.format(pattern, argument…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) function is designed just for this purpose.

In the properties file:

```
message.template.entities.associated = Entities {0} are already added in another association
```

In your code:

```
MessageFormat.format(getBundleResourceMessage("message.template.entities.associated"), appenMessage)
```

This will cause `appenMessage.toString()` to be substituted for the `{0}` placeholder.  The `MessageFormat` class also supports fancier variants of placeholders to support issues that you will encounter in internationalization, such as pluralization and date formatting.